# Knockout with HTML table issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

Basically, I have a page that displays multiple tables, all populated by knockout. Certain rows will now show up in this grid unless they are populated with data (special condition rows). I have a KO subscribed observable that observes whether or not there is data in the row.
Inside this subscription is a function that basically says:

```
self.requestSubscription = self.hasRequest.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        if (newValue) {
            $("[rowId = '6']").show(); // this 6 is hardcoded
        }
        else {
            $("[rowId = '6']").hide();
        }
    });
```

problem is, this function goes through EVERY grid on the page (cause I forgot that's how jquery works) and hides that row in every grid. How can I reduce this to hiding the grow in the current grid? Problem is I can't hardcode ID's into the grids because I don't know how many grids will show up on page load. Any ideas? Thanks!

Here is some html minus unnecessary content. This is the markup for the grid itself. Problem is, when I hide the tr with Id "6" with the jquery above, it does it very EVERY one of these grids on the page.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
         <!-- ko foreach: rows() -->
         <tr data-bind="css: { 'request': id() === 6, 'conflict': id() === 8}, attr: { rowId: id() }">
              <td class="title-cell">
                    <span data-bind="text: title(), attr: { TypeId: id() }">Booking Type</span>
              </td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the template you use for generating this table?

Comment: The markup or the javascript behind it?

Comment: Also include the logic/datasource behind `hasRequest`

Comment: Your subscription handler is part of the view model. And it is directly manipulating the DOM through jQuery. This weakens the clean separation between data object and the representation on the page. If you need very close control of the result, you should use a custom binding, outside of the view model.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of showing and hiding the row with jQuery, you should take advantage of Knockout's `visible` binding. Something like this:

```
<tr data-bind="visible: myTableModel.hasSpecialCondition">
    <td>Whatever</td>
</tr>
```

That way the display logic is connected to the data instead of the DOM.

Documentation here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html

Comment: I thought about this, but I probably should have elaborated that these rows aren't actually found in the markup.

basically, I do a <!-- ko foreach: rows() --> 
that runs through every row, then any specific styling for each row i can do one of these:

'data-bind="css: { 'request': id() === 6, 'conflict': id() === 8}, attr: { rowId: id() }"'

Comment: Could you post the HTML?

Comment: Is hasRequest available to the row? Could you do:

<tr data-bind="css: { 'request': id() === 6, 'conflict': id() === 8}, attr: { rowId: id() }, visible: hasRequest">

Comment: I COULD do that, but the issue is that the other rows would then become not visible due to the fact they don't have "hasRequest". "hasRequest" is only pertinent to one of the rows in the table. Sorry, this is way complicated!

Comment: This?
visible: (hasRequest() && id() == "6")

Comment: This certainly seems like the best idea. Thanks!